# Found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (Music Library)

Tags: arrays, swift, audio-player, optional-values

```
var songList = NSMutableArray()
var player = AVPlayer()
var isSelected = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    var songs = MPMediaQuery() // also tried var songs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
    var localSongs: NSArray = songs.items
    songList = NSMutableArray(array: localSongs)

    tableView.reloadData()

    var song: MPMediaItem = songList[0] as MPMediaItem // <<- Error here

    var currentItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as NSURL)

    player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(currentItem)

    player.play()

    var songTitle: NSString = song.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as NSString

    songName.text = songTitle 

    var time = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentItem.duration))
    sliderOutlet.value = time




}
```

I'm building a music player, but the app crasher when i run in the simulator and gives this error: `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`, and says this when i try run on iPhone : {

```
MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

EDIT: Seems like it's not accessing the local music library on my iPhone and adding songs to the array.

Comment: It says `songList` is empty. Are you sure there should be songs in it? I'd start there.

Comment: Isn't MPMediaQuery() supposed t collect songs from my local library? and the of course the simulator doesn't contain any songs.

Comment: Well, trace it back until you find the real problem. `songList` is empty. So is `localSongs` empty?

Comment: As for not working in the device, you don't give enough information to figure out where.  Specifically, on what line does it fail?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing an element without testing its size. So songList[0] is out of bounds, hence the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If your media query returns no items, then `localSongs` and `songlist` will both be arrays of size `0`.  When you then try to reference a song with `songList[0]` you will be accessing index `0` in an empty array.  Hence the crash.

Comment: OK, seems like it's not accessing the music library on my device and adding songs to the array, so how to do it then ?  i even changed " var songs = MPMediaQuery()" to "var songs = MPMediaQuery.songsQuey() "

Comment: I think I answered your original question.  Please up-vote and check this as 'answered'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a problem with expecting the simulator to have music in it.  Since it doesn't, songList.count == 0, which means songList[0] should generate an exception.  Seems like the expected and desired behavior to me.

Answer (score 0):

Put a check on count using `if` condition. You are accessing index which can be `nil`. If accessed it will through runtime error.

Preferred approach would it be wrapped explicitly with `?`

Comment: The array is empty, the problem now is how to add songs to it ?!